# Is there a Website Screenshot tool with command line utility in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, website, screenshot

I've looked through various such tools, but none of them are to be used in Linux:

http://mashable.com/2007/08/24/web-screenshots/

Comment: in the question you only mention Linux but in your comments below you ask for something that works on Windows.  please clarify what platform you need this tool to run on.

Answer (score 2):

Try **wkhtmltoimage** from [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) (check the downloads) Its great tool and ASAIK works on windows.

Answer (score 1):

[KHTML2PNG](http://khtml2png.sourceforge.net/) does that for Linux, using the KHTML rendering engine. We're using it in headless mode on servers.

Comment: Can it work in windows?Because I develop in windows.

Comment: The title said you were searching for a Linux tool though...

Comment: Yes,the build is on linux.But dev is on windows.

Comment: @user11671: What?  Rewrite your question to explain exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Link shows abandoned project. Pls fix the link, probably project hosted somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Add-on for Firefox called [Screengrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146) that places an icon in the browser status bar. Not command line, but either Linux or Windows, and handy.

Comment: Screengrab also places an entry in your context menu so you can right-click in the browser and select screengrab.

Answer (score 1):

We use [wkhtml2pdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) which is a static build of the Webkit rendering engine (as used by Safari, Chrome et al.) and generates a **PDF**. Not quite a JPEG/PNG screenshot, but it serves a different purpose for us. (As an added bonus, you can still copy the original text as-is.)

It works on Linux, OS X and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) which also works on Windows, Linux and Mac OSX can to this with the following command (code stolen from my [Fluxbox](http://fluxbox.org/) menu)

```
import screenshot.jpg && display -resize 50% screenshot.jpg
```

Comment: I get the following error: `import.im6: unable to open X server ' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/368.`. Plus, where do you specify the URL?

Answer (score 0):

There is an addon for firefox called Pearl Crescent that has command line access:https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/pagesaver/?src=collection&collection_id=23ccef22-af27-4a82-806a-568db8935e21